# Apache Camel support for Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I've searched for information about Apache Camel supporting the new Spring Boot 3, but with no results.

My question is: Did Apache Camel announce the support for Spring Boot 3?

All I can find is Apache Camel is only to version <3.0 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [spring integration 6.0 goes General availability](https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/29/spring-integration-6-0-goes-ga) was announced just some days before.

As you can see in the 5th iteration of that project ([link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/releases/tag/v6.0.0-M5)), there was added some support for apache camel.

You can read more about this [here.](https://spring.io/blog/2022/09/21/spring-integration-6-0-0-m5-and-5-5-15-available)

So considering that you already have `spring-boot-starter-parent` in your dependencies, you now you have the following 2 dependencies to be used to enable communication channels with apache-camel.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
</dependency>
 
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 7):

Apache Camel will support Spring Boot 3 from Apache Camel 4.x.

For Camel 3 we are going to be on Spring Boot 2.x.

Comment: Spring Boot 3.X runs on java 17 and Apache Camel 3.17 as well, does it mean that Apache Camel 3.17 on support Spring Boot 3 ?

Comment: Camel 3.17 is not designed to work with Spring Boot 3 and I don't know how you are able to run an application based on Spring Boot 3 with Camel-Spring-Boot 3.17

Comment: Can you please help to provide the information source of this?

Comment: I'm one of the core developers and the current PMC chair of the Apache Camel project.