# Migrate an application to Spring boot 3.0 which uses camel-spring-boot-starter while waiting for Camel 4

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am migrating an application to Spring boot 3.0, but I have a problem with the injection of a ProducerTemplate in one of my services (annotation @Service se Spring Boot).
I was using the Spring Boot starter from Camel
Current Spring Boot version is : 2.7.5

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-rabbitmq-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My ProducerTemplate is injected into the constructor of my service that extends RouteBuilder

```java
    @Service
    public class MyServiceImpl extends RouteBuilder implements MyService {
    
        private final ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;
    
        @Autowired
        public MyServiceImpl(ProducerTemplate producerTemplate) {
            this.producerTemplate = producerTemplate;
        }
```

At startup, the application crashes with this message :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.mycompany.ServiceImpl required a bean of type 'org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate' in your configuration.
```

It's not very clear to me how I should take it.
I guess I have to use the dependency

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

instead of

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

But I don't really know how I should instantiate the ProducerTemplate and the CamelContext ?

I tried without really believing something like this :

```java
    @Configuration
    public class CamelConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public CamelContext getCamelContext() throws Exception {
            CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
            if (context.isStopped()) context.start();
            return context;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public ProducerTemplate getProducerTemplate() throws Exception
        {
            final ProducerTemplate template = getCamelContext().createProducerTemplate();
            return template;
        }
    
    }

    @Service
    public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    
        private final ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;
    
        private CamelContext context;
        
        @Autowired
        public MyServiceImpl(ProducerTemplate producerTemplate, CamelContext context) {
            this.producerTemplate = producerTemplate;
            this.context = context;
            try {
                this.context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                    @Override
                    public void configure() throws Exception {
    
                        from("direct:update-legacy")
                                .to("bean:updateJdbc");
```

The app failed with the following error message :

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: bean://updateJdbc due to: No bean could be found in the registry for: updateJdbc
```

Comment: does that help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74701345/apache-camel-support-for-spring-boot-3

Comment: @BenayaTrabelsi Not really, at least I don't understand how.
Not really, at least I don't understand how.
I am able to create a CamelContext and a ProducerTemplate but I am stumped when it comes to adding the routes. I don't do it correctly and it tells me that it can't find them in the registry

Comment: the first answer mention that SB 3.0 is supported yet, and the latest 3.20.0 of camel, is made for SB 2.7.6, so it may not work, at least not out of the box

Comment: @BenayaTrabelsi Yes indeed
But as you can use Camel without Spring, I guess you can still work with Spring Boot 3, only, we don't take advantage of all the magic of the integration provided by camel-spring-boot-starter

Answer (score 0):

From this link [Apache Camel support for Spring boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74701345/apache-camel-support-for-spring-boot-3), the issue is that Apache Camel don't support Spring Boot 3. It will support it from Apache Camel 4.x.
In case you are using Apache Camel 3.x, use Spring Boot 2.7.x.