# can we use springboot 3 with apache camel?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I resolve some fixes vulnerabilites in a java application and we have a critical issue https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/cve-2016-1000027 the point here is the current version of springboot is 2.7.2  and migrate version for use springboot  3.0.0  the camel 3 context not load, Does anyone know if spring boot 3 is compatible with any version of camel3?

Comment: *I can't find documentation about it.* Which kind of answers it. I do recall they stopped offering the spring integration module (`camel-spring`) so you ned to write your own nowadays, so it might work if you rework your configuration. But you probably need an updated Camel as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Camel support for Spring Boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74701345/apache-camel-support-for-spring-boot-3)

Answer (score 1):

[Camel 4](https://camel.apache.org/blog/2023/01/camel4roadmap/) will support Spring Boot 3. Until then, I'd recommend upgrading to the latest Spring Boot 2.7.x release.