# ActiveMQ Artemis + Spring Boot 3 + Apache Camel - RouteBuilder is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, message-queue, activemq-artemis

I created a very simple Spring Boot 3.0 project with Apache Camel and ActiveMQ Artemis since ActiveMQ "Classic" support has been discontinued in Spring Boot 3. My MQ routes are not working. Any help here is really appreciated.

`pom.xml` dependencies:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.28.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jms-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.20.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.20.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ArtemisApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ArtemisApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

`application.properties`:

```
spring.artemis.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
camel.springboot.auto-startup=true
spring.artemis.password=admin
spring.artemis.user=admin
spring.artemis.mode=native
camel.servlet.mapping.context-path=/services/*
```

RouteBuilder class:

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ArtemisMQRouter extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("activemq:queue:input")
                .routeId("ArtemisMQRouter ")
                .id("activemq:queue:input")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log, "Message received from activemq:queue:input")
                .to("activemq:queue:output")                
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log, "Message successfully sent to the activemq:queue:output")
                .end();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are there any error or warn messages?

Comment: For what it's worth, the [Camel 3 documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/activemq-component.html) states, "The ActiveMQ component is an extension to the JMS component and has been pre-configured for using Apache ActiveMQ 5.x (not Artemis). Users of Apache ActiveMQ Artemis should use the JMS component."

Comment: I referred to documentation but it didn't help. Queues are not getting created in artemis @JustinBertram

Comment: How do you know the queues are not getting created in ActiveMQ Artemis? Are there any error or warn messages? Please elaborate. You aren't providing enough information to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: No errors. I am not able to see the queue in artemis console where as in old application - springboot 2 with artemis queues are getting created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Camel support for Spring Boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74701345/apache-camel-support-for-spring-boot-3)

Answer (score -1):

You need Apache Camel v4 to work with Spring Boot 3.
Camel v3 is only compatible with Spring Boot 2.

Comment: I tried with 4.0.0m2 it didn't work